# Encrypting data with forgejs on the client side, and decrypting with ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, encryption, aes

For a given project, I'm looking to encrypt a piece of data with AES 256, and then RSA encrypt the key. I've been using Forge and the Encryptor gem in ruby, and i can't seem get matching encryption values:

```
var key = 'strengthstrengthstrengthstrength';
var iv =  'cakecakecakecakecakecakecakecake';
var cipher = forge.aes.createEncryptionCipher(key, 'CBC');
cipher.start(iv);
cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer("some string"));
cipher.finish();

var encrypted = cipher.output;
console.log(btoa(encrypted.data)); // outputs: CjLmWObDO2Dlwa5tJnRBRw==
```

Then in IRB:

```
Encryptor.encrypt 'some string', :key => 'strengthstrengthstrengthstrength', :key => 'cakecakecakecakecakecakecakecake'
Base64.encode64 _
# outputs: C9Gtk9YfciVMJEsbhZrQTw==\n
```

Over using string values for Key & IV, tried:

```
var key = forge.random.getBytesSync(32);
var iv = forge.random.getBytesSync(32);
```

Then doing a `btoa()` call on each of them. Using the `Base64.decode64` on the ruby side, before passing them to `Encryptor.decrypt`, but still no luck.

Any idea where i've gone wrong?

Comment: Did you copy-paste the actual Encryptor.encrypt line above? The second :key should be :iv, shouldn't it?

Comment: The IV value is too long anyway, you should use a 16 byte IV, not one that hold s 32 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. Since i'm just using one key to encrypt one value, i just used the key as the IV & Salt as well. **This is not recommended** if you are using the key to encrypt multiple values. You will then need to generate proper salt & iv values.

Also the gen key value is a pretty poor way, as `Math.random` is not secure. Just ran out of time to do this properly, but works okay for this case.

```
var Encryption = (function () {

  var api = {
    getKey: function () {
      var possible = "ABCDEFabcdef0123456789";
      var key = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        key += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
      }
      return key;
    },

    encryptPII: function (rawKey, value) {
      var salt = rawKey;
      var iv = rawKey;
      var key = forge.pkcs5.pbkdf2(rawKey, salt, 2000, 32);
      var cipher = forge.aes.createEncryptionCipher(key, 'CBC');
      cipher.start(iv);
      cipher.update(forge.util.createBuffer(value));
      cipher.finish();

      return btoa(cipher.output.data);
    }
  };
  return api;
})();
```

The `rawKey` is the value returned from `getKey()`. The `value` property is the the string to be encrypted. I use the rawkey for iv & salt values, generate a key in the same way that the [Encryptor gem](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/encryptor/blob/0fcb609ec99afa1b47bba0c2f6fe29f6137075f2/lib/encryptor.rb#L66) in ruby does. Use forge to then encrypt the string value.

If i take the base64, decode it in ruby, and pass the same `rawKey` value to the encryptor gem for key, salt and iv, it works.